# Perl: Read/Reverse Data Dumper back into an array

Tags: perl

My goal is to read a string back into an array ref.

I modified the example code [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=845672). The example on that site uses a Hash and in my case I want to use an Array. Here is what I tried:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# Build an array with a hash inside
my @test_array = ();
my %test_hash = ();
$test_hash{'ding'} = 'dong';
push @test_array, \%test_hash;

# Get the Dumper output as a string
my $output_string = Dumper(\@test_array);

# eval_result should be an array but is undef
my @eval_result = @{eval $output_string};
```

Running this code produces this error:

```
Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference at
        /var/tmp/test_dumper.pl line 30 (#1)
    (F) A value used as either a hard reference or a symbolic reference must
    be a defined value.  This helps to delurk some insidious errors.

Uncaught exception from user code:
        Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference at /var/tmp/test_dumper.pl line 30.
 at /var/tmp/test_dumper.pl line 30.
        main::test_array_dump() called at /var/tmp/test_dumper.pl line 14
```

If I remove the `use strict;` pragma, the error goes away and I get the expected array.

What is the correct way to get an array variable from a Dumper output?

Comment: It might be worth using something like JSON instead of Dumper output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be checking `$@` after any `eval` that unexpectedly fails.

The `Dumper` output by default will begin with `$VAR1 = ...`. If you have not declared `$VAR1` in the current scope, then under `use strict` your `Dumper` output will fail to compile and `$@` will contain the dreaded `Global symbol $VAR1 requires explicit package ...` message.

So if you are using `strict` and calling `eval` on `Dumper` output, declare `$VAR1`.

```
my $VAR1;
my $array_ref = eval($output_string);
die $@ unless $array_ref;
```

Comment: That was just it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass an array reference to Dumper rather than the array itself, i.e.:

```
my $output_string = Dumper(\@test_array);
```

The following works for me:

```
my $output_string = Dumper(\@test_array);

# eval_result should be an Array but is undef
my @eval_result = @{eval $output_string};
print Dumper(\@eval_result);
```

results in:

```
$VAR1 = [
    {
        'ding' => 'dong'
    }
];
```

See also examples in [Dumper documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~ilyam/Data-Dumper-2.121/Dumper.pm).

Comment: Thanks @swornabsent. In the event that I'm given a string by another application (which dumped the array not the ref), is there a way to read the string back into an array?

Comment: @DirtyPenguin that could be a challenge, I'm not sure of a hard and fast way or a module that does it offhand. I think all you'd have to do is write something to strip the leading  `$VAR2..$VAR_n_` strings and wrap square brackets around the whole thing, should be doable. Sorry I can't point you to something quick and easy.

Comment: I updated the code to dump the array ref. But I still get an undef when I try to eval that string. Any ideas?

Comment: @DirtyPenguin you can keep the array assignment. I edited code that works for me into my answer.

Comment: It works when I remove the `use strict;` pragma. I've updated the question. Any ideas how to get it working with `use strict;`?